# Overload template operator of template class that uses SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have a template class (with SFINAE condition) and I'd like to overload a template `operator <<` for it.

This code works, but it also allow all `operator <<` overloaded for all types `T` to access `Foo` as friends.

How can I get only `operator <<` of type `Foo` to be `friend` of `Foo` class?

I tried forward declaration of `Foo` class and `operator` but can make it work because of the use of `enable_if`

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

```
template< typename T, enable_if_t< condition_v<T>, int> = 0 >
class Foo
{
    // ...

    template< typename Ar, typename R> friend Ar& operator<<(Ar& os, const Foo<R>& foo);          
};

template< typename Ar, typename T>
inline Ar& operator<<(Ar& ar, const Foo<T>& foo)
{
   // ...
   return ar;
}
```

Comment: Why is `Ar` a template parameter anyway? Why not just `std::ostream`?

Comment: Why do you think that all types are no friends of `Foo`? Only `operator<<` has been declared a friend.

Comment: @Jan Schultke:  Because Ar is not an std::ostream
I only required << to be friend sice it nedd to access private members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to resolve `friend` and `template` issues is to define the `friend` within the class<sup>(1)</sup>, usually:

```cpp
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t< condition_v<T>, int> = 0 >
class Foo
{
    template< typename Ar > friend Ar& operator<<(Ar& os, const Foo& foo) {
        // ...
        return os;
    }          
};
```

Note that this defines a function template where `Foo` is not a template parameter.
Only `Ar` is a template parameter.
This is typically desirable because it simplifies overload resolution, which can fix some ambiguous cases, and it may improve compilation speed.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Colloquially, such a `friend` is called "hidden friend".</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> I tried forward declaration of Foo class and operator but can make it work because of the use of enable_if

The correct way to do this would be to *specify the default argument in the forward declaration* of the class template.

More importantly, **once you've specified the default argument in the forward declaration, you don't have to specify it in the definition** of the class template as shown below:

```
//forward declaration. Here we specify the default argument
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t< condition_v<T>, int> = 0 > 
class Foo;
//also a forward declaration
template< typename Ar, typename R> Ar& operator<<(Ar& os, const Foo<R>& foo);

//note here we don't specify the default argument
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t< condition_v<T>, int>>
class Foo
{
    

    template< typename Ar, typename R> friend Ar& operator<<(Ar& os, const Foo<R>& foo);           
};

//definition outside the class as you want
template< typename Ar, typename T>
inline Ar& operator<<(Ar& ar, const Foo<T>& foo)
{
   return ar;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YEbcsY3ee)